# Jasper Reports Master Detail Report

Tags: jasper-reports, master-detail

Is it possible to create a Master-detail report in Jasper without creating a sub-report. Does Jasper provide some component or option so that I don't end up with 2 jrxml file for a simple Master-Detail report.
I'm providing the datasource in form of POJOs.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can do Master-Detail reports with a Table component or a List component. Your post doesn't really have enough information to say with certainty that these will work in your case, but you should start by taking a look at those.